# Android: Customizing ListView for music button

Tags: android, listview

I have updated my List view values from an array list but now I want to add two buttons in each row of list view just for playing and stopping sound. How can I add buttons in List View manually ,I mean by code or any other source. 
Here is what I have done

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(now);
        prayerTimes = prayers.getPrayerTimes(cal, latitude,
                longitude, timezone);
        ArrayList prayerNames = prayers.getTimeNames();
       ArrayList<String>list= new ArrayList<String>();
       for (int i = 0; i < prayerTimes.size(); i++) 
        {
           if(i==0||i==2||i==3||i==5||i==6)
           {
              list.add((String)prayerNames.get(i)+"-"+(String)prayerTimes.get(i));
           }
         }
       ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
       azanList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

### Now I want to add 2 buttons like this

### Fajar- 4:05am         **Play**   **Stop**

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at :

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

http://hmkcode.com/android-custom-listview-items-row/

Custom listview is all you need